# How to kill Wagtail server?

Tags: server, localhost, devops, wagtail, linode

I've completed the installation process for Wagtail on Linode but haven't deployed yet. I started the server with `./manage.py runserver` but accidentally exited without stopping the server. The `./manage.py help` command doesn't show how to stop the server. What's the best way to stop it so that I can restart it on 0.0.0.0:8000? Should I just reboot the Linode server? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Killing the process will stop the wagtail server.

First search for your process id (PID), filtering by "manage.py runserver"

```
ps aux | grep "manage.py runserver"
```

You will see something like this:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
[...]
user        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2433   0:00 python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

Then you can kill your process using `kill -9 $PID`, in this example `$PID` is 38:

```
# Terminate running process    
kill -9 38
```

Now you should be able to start your app normaly with using:

`./manage.py runserver`

Restarting your Linode server will also solve this, but its like killing a fly with a hammer :)

Comment: Thanks! I got three entries when running the command > http://pastebin.com/4kJD30fU should I kill all of them?

Comment: I think just killing `/home/emtr0/Env/emtr0dotcom/bin/python ./manage.py runserver` will do the trick, if not, kill also the first one. The last one is the grep process used for doing the actual filtering of `ps aux`, so there is no need on killing that one.